# converting a recursive formula into a non-recursive formula.

Tags: recurrence-relations

We found a recursive formula for the following problem:

For any positive integer $n$, let $b(n)$ be the number of ways that you can write $n$ as a sum using only the numbers 1, 2, and 3 where the order of the sum doesn’t matter.

our recursive formula is $$b(n) = b(n-3)+b(n-2)-b(n-5)+1$$
from the values $$b(0)=1, b(1)=1, b(2)=2, b(3)=3, b(4)=4, b(5)=5, b(6)=7, b(7)=8, b(8)=10, b(9)=12, b(10)=14$$

we are trying to find a non-recursive formula for this sequence, so that we can find the values for $b$ at 2012 through 2017

please also explain HOW to get the formula, as this is for marks.

Comment: There's a lot of theory to be found [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). Especially see the sections _Solving non-homogeneous recurrence relations_ and _Linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients_. Note that the general method will have you solving a 6th-degree equation, so it may not be practical here.

Comment: This is [A001399](http://oeis.org/A001399) -- in fact the first hit found by searching the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences for your known values. It gives the simple formula $b(n)=\operatorname{round}(\frac{(n+3)^2}{12})$.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way to get a closed form for that recurrence would be first to get rid of the constant term by subtracting the equation for $n-1$ from the one for $n$:

```
   b(n)          = b(n-2) + b(n-3)          - b(n-5)          + 1
-         b(n-1) =          b(n-3) + b(n-4)          - b(n-6) + 1
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   b(n) = b(n-1) + b(n-2)          - b(n-4) - b(n-5) + b(n-6)
```

You then need to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial of this equation,
$$t^6 - t^5 - t^4 + t^2 + t - 1 $$
I cheated and used Wolfram Alpha for that, but it can also be done by hand in this case because there are many $\pm1$ roots. It factors as
$$ (t^3-1)(t^2-1)(t-1) = (t+1)(t-1)^2(t^3-1) = (t+1)(t-1)^3(t-\zeta)(t-\zeta^2) $$
where $\zeta$ is a complex third root of unity. (That $(t^3-1)(t^2-1)(t-1)$ factorization sure looks like it has something to do with the 1,2,3 of your original problem statement, doesn't it?)

So the general solution of the recurrence is
$$ b(n) = c_1 + c_2n + c_3n^2 + c_4(-1)^n + c_5\zeta^n + c_6\zeta^{2n} $$
Since the sequence is obviously real, we must have $c_5=c_6$, so this becomes
$$ b(n) = c_1 + c_2n + c_3n^2 + c_4(-1)^n + c_5 \cdot\begin{cases} 2 & \text{when }3\mid n \\ -1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

You will then need to find the $c_i$s by solving the system of linear equations you get by plugging in 5 known values of $b(n)$. Finally you can plug $n=2012$ and so forth into the formula.

**Edit:** Oops -- the appropriate condition for the result to be real is not $c_5=c_6$, but $c_5=\overline{c_6}$, and there can be an imaginary part in these constants. It is probably easiest then to subsume $c_1$, $c_5$ and $c_6$ into new (real) constants $k_0$, $k_1$, $k_2$, and write
$$ \tag{*} b(n) = c_2n + c_3n^2 + c_4(-1)^n + k_{n\,\bmod\,3}$$
Then *six* known values of $b(n)$ are necessary to find all of the constants -- and a good thing that, because five values would not have been enough to know from the sample values what the constant term we started out by eliminating from the recurrence was.

**Even more edit:** Note that the form of $(*)$ makes good geometric sense, since the original problem

> let b(n) be the number of ways that you can write n as a sum using only the numbers 1, 2, and 3 where the order of the sum doesn’t matter.

simply asks for the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $2x+3y\le n$, or in other words the number of points with integral coordinates in a triangle bounded by the horizontal and vertical axes and a line with slope $-\frac32$. To a first approximation we'd expect this to be $\frac 12 (n/3)(n/2)$, so we ought to have $c_3=\frac{1}{12}$. The other terms are there just to correct for fencepost errors. It is to be expected that there are corrections with period 2 and 3 as the axis intercepts of the hypotenuse sweeps past lattice points. It may be surprising that there is no similar periodic variation in the coefficient of the linear term $c_2n$, but that is probably because $2$ and $3$ are coprime, so the density of lattice points on the hypotenuse is the same for all $n$. It would be a different matter if it had been "using only the numbers 1, 2 and 4", for example. **End edits.**

---

If simply finding the values of $b(2012)$ upto $b(2017)$ is all you want, it is probably less work just to program a computer to fill in a table of $b(n)$ upto that number, using your recursive equation to fill in each value based on the ones you have already computed.

Answer (score 1):

Write the recurrence as:
$$
b(n + 5) = b(n + 3) + b(n + 2) - b(n) + 1
$$
Define the generating function:
$$
B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b(n) z^n
$$
Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize sums like:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} b(n + r) z^n
  &= \frac{B(z) - b(0) - b(1) z - \ldots - b(r - 1) z^{r - 1}}{z^r} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
  &= \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{B(z) - b(0) - b(1) z - b(2) z^2 - b(3) z^3 - b(4) z^4}{z^5}
  = \frac{B(z) - b(0) - b(1) z - b(2) z^2}{z^3}
       + \frac{B(z) - b(0) - b(1) z}{z^2}
       - B(z)
       + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Solving and writing as partial fractions:
\begin{align}
B(z)
  &= \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2 + z^4 + z^5 - z^6} \\
  &= \frac{17}{72} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
       + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
       + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3}
       - \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + z}
       - \frac{2 + z}{9 (1 + z + z^2)}
\end{align}
The first terms are easy to handle by the generalized binomial theorem,
for $m$ a positive integer:
$$
(1 + u)^{-m}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
$$
Note that $\binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1}$ is a polynomial of degree $m - 1$ in $k$.

We are left with (here $\omega = - (1 + \mathrm{i} \sqrt{3}) / 2$ is a cubic root of 1):
\begin{align}
B_2(z)
  &= \frac{2 + z}{1 + z + z^2} \\
  &= \frac{2 + z}{(1 - \omega z) (1 - \omega^2 z)} \\
  &= \frac{1}{1 - \omega z} - \frac{1}{1 - \omega^2 z}
\end{align}
This is definitely getting ugly...

We could also write:
\begin{align}
B_2(z)
  &= \frac{2 + z}{1 + z + z^2} \\
  &= \frac{(2 + z) (1 - z)}{1 - z^3} \\
  &= \frac{2 - z - z^2}{1 - z^3}
\end{align}
What $B_2$ contributes to $b(n)$ is the coefficient of $z^n$:
\begin{align}
[z^n] B_2(z)
  &= [z^n] \frac{2 - z - z^2}{1 - z^3} \\
  &= 2 [z^n] (1 - z^3)^{-1}
      - [z^{n - 1}] (1 - z^3)^{-1}
      - [z^{n - 2}] (1 - z^3)^{-1} \\
  &= \begin{cases}
         2 & \text{if } 3 \mid n \\
        -1 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
\end{align}
Splicing all the above together gives a formula for $b(n)$, which can be used to compute the values asked for.