# what percentage of the integers in the range $l,l+1,\dots k$ contain a certain digit?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

what percentage of the integers in the range $l,l+1,\dots k$ contain a certain digit?

For example, say `l is 0`, `k is 9`, and my digit is `3`.  The range of numbers (`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`) contains only one number with a `3` digit, thus the percentage would be 1/10 = 10%.

As another example, `l is 25`, `k is 35`, and my digit is `3`. Now the range looks like (`25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35`), Of which, 6/11 contain `3` for a percent of 54.54%. Note that you o not double count 33, as while it contains 2 `3`s, it is still only one number.

Some things that I've concluded so far:

**$k-l$ approaches infinity, the limit  is 1.**
$$\lim_{(k-l)\rightarrow \infty } f(k,l)=1$$

and that's about it so far, I've been scratching my head as to how to solve this for a while now, and have never really found a way to do so.

Comment: @Jorge oi, what happened to the question!? haha

Comment: @Jorge: I agree with tuskiomi $-$ your edit was destructive. Why did you remove the helpful examples?

Comment: @TonyK I tried to edit a hybrid of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $A$ instead of $l$ and $Z$ instead of $k$, as they were in the original question.  The use of $k$ conflicts with the use in my answer below.

It is easier to define $g(n,d)$ as the number of numbers from $0$ to $n$ that contain digit $d$.  To get the number in the range $A$ to $Z$ you can do $g(Z,d)-g(A-1,d)$.  You can divide by $Z-A+1$ to get the fraction.

You can write a recursive calculation for $g(n,d)$  We will do the case $d \neq 0$.  There are corrections because we don't put leading zeros on numbers.  There are $10^k$ numbers with up to $k$ digits.  $9^k$ of them do not contain a $d$, so there are $10^k-9^k$ that do contain a $d$.  If $n$ is not of the form $10^k-1$ we accept that count with the largest $k$ possible and add on the ones that come later.  If there are any that start with $d$, they will all contain a $d$.  The rest will contain a $d$ if there is one in the last $k$ digits.

So express $n=(10^k-1)+m$ for the largest $k$ possible.
$$g(n,d)=\begin {cases}10^k-9^k&m=0\\
10^k-9^k+g(m,d)& m\lt d\cdot 10^k\\
10^k-9^k+(m-10^k+1)+(d-1)g(10^{k-1}-1,d)&d\cdot 10^k \le m \lt (d+1)10^k\\
10^k-9^k+10^k(d-1)+(d-1)g(10^{k-1}-1,d)+g(m-10^kd,d) & m \ge (d+1)10^k \end {cases}$$